# Form Key Validation Error

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, error, form-validation, form-key

So I have fixed my form key validation issues but my admin is still showing an error message.

```
Important: Formkey validation on checkout disabled. This may expose security risks. We strongly recommend to Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout in Admin / Security Section, for protect your own checkout process.
```

Does anyone know how i can get rid of this error? What file is this text on?

Comment: Have you set "Yes" for Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout at `Admin / Security` ?

Comment: Please see my updates in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set "Yes" for `Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout` at`Admin / Security`.

If you set `Yes` above error will gone!.

**Important!** Enabling this option means that your custom templates used in checkout process contain `form_key` output. Otherwise checkout may not work.

**Update I**

If you need to hide message without enabling `Yes`. You need to create a small module. In this module we will override `system.xml` and create a new source model.

Idea is if we set `Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout` to `No` message will display. You don't want to set it to `Yes`, So we need a third option.

Create following files:

> app/etc/modules/Mago_Pawan.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mago_Pawan>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Mago_Pawan>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Mago/Pawan/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mago_Pawan>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Mago_Pawan>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <pawan>
                <class>Mago_Pawan_Model</class>
            </pawan>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Mago/Pawan/etc/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <admin>
            <groups>
                <security>
                    <fields>
                        <validate_formkey_checkout translate="label">
                            <label>Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout$$$$@@@</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>pawan/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                            <comment><![CDATA[<strong style="color:red">Important!</strong> Enabling this option means
                            that your custom templates used in checkout process contain form_key output.
                            Otherwise checkout may not work.]]></comment>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        </validate_formkey_checkout>
                    </fields>
                </security>
            </groups>
        </admin>
    </sections>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Mago/Pawan/Model/System/Config/Source/Yesno.php

```
<?php
class Mago_Pawan_Model_System_Config_Source_Yesno
{

    /**
     * Options getter
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value' => 2, 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('I will manage')),
            array('value' => 1, 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Yes')),
            array('value' => 0, 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('No')),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get options in "key-value" format
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        return array(
            0 => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('No'),
            1 => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Yes'),
            2 => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('I will manage'),
        );
    }

}
```

**Note:** After successful create/install module, you will see a third option. Just select this and it will work!

**Update II**

If you want `comment/hide` message without module you can check below file:

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml

```
<?php if ($this->canShow()): ?>
    <div class="notification-global notification-global-warning">
        <strong style="color:red">Important: </strong>
        <span>Formkey validation on checkout disabled. This may expose security risks.
        We strongly recommend to Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout in
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getSecurityAdminUrl(); ?>">Admin / Security Section</a>,
        for protect your own checkout process. </span>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can `comment/hide` entire code, above file is responsible for showing only this `form_key` message so it will not harm any other functionality.

If you look block class for above phtml, there is a function

```
public function canShow()
    {
        return !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('admin/security/validate_formkey_checkout');
    }
```

It is checking value of system config and based on value showing message in admin.

Comment: I have already fixed the issue but I do not want to set config to yes. I would like to remove the error from the code. Any idea where I can find this error?

Comment: thank you. Is there a simpler way to hide this notice? Where is this notice in the code?

Comment: it is very short module and only take less than 5 min. I have another solution, see my `updates II` in answer

Comment: Thanks so much! the second one worked fine.

Comment: Great!,  Always welcome :)